# Spring data - two different data sources on the same transaction causing abnormality

Tags: spring, spring-data, transactional, atomikos, transactionmanager

We are using atomikos JTA with spring and 2 different mysql datasources.

We got a problem,

When we use two different repositories (of 2 different datasources)  on the same @Transactional method we get an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to enlist connection the transaction
```

This happens when the second repository is doing some action against the data source.

We believe it got something to do with the transaction manager (atomikos jta) that might have issues when 2 different data sources are involved in the same transaction.

here is the datasources xml:

```
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" />
    <property name="url" value="${mysql_url}" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.BasicManagedDataSource">
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="xaDataSourceInstance" ref="xaDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.model" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="JTA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- shared data source -->

<bean id="shardXaDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" />
    <property name="url" value="${shared_mysql_url}" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
</bean>

<bean id="shareddDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.BasicManagedDataSource">
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="xaDataSourceInstance" ref="shardXaDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="sharedEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.shared.model" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="shareddDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="JTA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the transaction.xml :

```
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager
    transaction-manager="atomikosTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="atomikosTransactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

*** EDIT (19.01.2014) ***

So according to M. Deinum help we managed to make the error go away, but now there is no actuall transaction taking place (on exception for example there is no roll back)

Here is our new configuration:

data-source.xml:

```
    <bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" />
    <property name="url" value="${mysql_url}" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="6918001" />
</bean>

   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xaDataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.model" />
  <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
         <prop     key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup        </prop>
     </props>
   </property>
 <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
         <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
         <property name="showSql" value="false" />
         <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
     </bean>
 </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="shardXaDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" />
    <property name="url" value="${shared_mysql_url}" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="6918001" />
</bean>


 <bean id="sharedEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="jtaDataSource" ref="shardXaDataSource" />
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.shared.model" />
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

transaction.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" /> 


 <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
<property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
<property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
 <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
 <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
 <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

*** EDIT 01/20/2014 ***

We managed to make it work but tons of warnings on startup:

```
   20 Jan 2014 15:14:16  WARN AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'xaDataSource': poolSize equals default - this may cause performance problems!
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:17  WARN JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000427: Using deprecated    org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup strategy [hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class],        use newer org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform strategy instead    [hibernate.transaction.jta.platform]
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@4063a38e: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'sharedXaDataSource': poolSize equals default - this may cause performance problems!
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000427: Using deprecated org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup strategy [hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class], use newer org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform strategy instead [hibernate.transaction.jta.platform]
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@3d00772f: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN EntityManagerFactoryRegistry - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN UserTransactionServiceImp - No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN UserTransactionServiceImp - transactions.properties not found - looking for jta.properties in classpath...
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN UserTransactionServiceImp - Failed to open transactions properties file - using default values
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator     10.0.50.117.tm0050100104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050100104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050200104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050200104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050300104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050300104 with state COMMITTING
20 Jan 2014 15:14:18  WARN CoordinatorImp - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 10.0.50.117.tm0050400104 with state COMMITTING
```

The new configuration is :

```
<bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="uniqueResourceName"><value>xaDataSource</value></property>      
     <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${mysql_url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">xxx</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sharedXaDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="uniqueResourceName"><value>sharedXaDataSource</value></property>
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${shared_mysql_url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">xxx</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager
    transaction-manager="atomikosTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="atomikosTransactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Your configuration is flawed and contains duplication, which probably, confuses spring. Both the `JtaTransactionManager` as well as `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` create a `JtaTransactionManager`.

Next your `<tx:annotation-driven >` should point to a `JtaTransactionManager` but nog it points to a `UserTransactionManager`.

So first fix your configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Assuming you are using a recent Spring 3.2 version instead of injecting the `dataSource` property inject the `jtaDataSource` on your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, next your `jpaProperties` and `jpaPropertiesMap` can be cleaned up.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xaDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.model" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The `hibernate.connection` properties are useless as you are injecting a Spring managed datasource. Due to the injection of the `jtaDataSource` the jpaProperty for `javax.persistence.transactionType` can be removed. The `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` already sets the `HibernateJpaDialect` and you can use the `databasePlatform` property to specify the dialect.

Regarding your datasources you should be using the Atomikos wrappers for the datasources so that they are aware of Atomikos. For this use the `AtomikosDataSourceBean` instead of the xa provided datasource for your JDBC driver.

```
<bean id="xaDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" />
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="xaDataSource"/>      
     <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${mysql_url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">xxx</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Finally you are using the `BasicDataSource` as a reference to hibernate whereas you should use the xa enabled (and wrapped) datasource.

Comment: M.Deinum, The Error now is not being thrown and that's great news!.  however, now a rollback is not being issued for all my entites (from either datasource). for example if my service is annotatoed with @Transactional and i persist an entity inside it, if an error is being thrown after there is no rollback :(, Iv'e edited my original post with the changes i made. Thanks!

Comment: Is there no rollback in the logging or no rollback in the database? YOu are using MySQL so also make sure you use transactional table types (InnoDB and not MyISAM). You might want to enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and see what happens (if a tx is properly started etc.).

Comment: Thanks Deinum, We did as you suggested, we have an error in our logs. we put it on the original post (*** edit2 ***)

Comment: That is a debug message that you cannot manually rollback (but have to mark the transaction as rollback only). Shouldn't be your problem, as mentioned check your database. What I miss in your stacktrace is something indicating that spring is part of this transaction setup (I see no spring transactioninterceptor or the likes).

Comment: Transactioninterceptor is nowhere to be seen:/ what could it be? why spring is not part of this transaction? Does this orchestra has any other required configuration that we haven't mentioned in the original post?

Comment: How are you loading your configuration and how are you bootstrapping your services? Can you post a stacktrace from where you expect a rollback to happen?

Comment: OK, We have managed to make it work, transactioninterceptor  is now part of the transactions and all working as expected, but we have tons of warnings on startup- see my ***edit  3 ***

Comment: A couple of warnings are due to the use of deprecated API's in hibernate for which there isn't a replacement yet (AFAIK). Ignore the configuration one (imho that should be info but alas). The other ones I cannot help you with my, my Atomikos knowledge is lacking.

Comment: Thanks alot  M. Deinum for your help! We will see to the warnings specifically

Answer (score 0):

Try this: On your transaction Managers add:

```
<qualifier value="transactionManager1"/>
```

example:

```
<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
    <qualifier value="transactionManager1"/>
</bean>
```

then in you DAO implementation do something like this:

```
@Repository("Users1DAO")
public class Users1DAOJpaImp implements Users1DAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="datasources1")
    @Qualifier("transactionTemplate1")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager1",  readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void save(Users1 user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }

}
```